# What is the Catholic teaching on tattoos?

Tags: catholicism, human-body, tattoos

Leviticus 19:28

> You will not gash your bodies when someone dies, and you will not
> tattoo yourselves. I am Yahweh.

In this article: [Pope Francis Gives His Blessing for Tattoos](http://www.breitbart.com/national-security/2018/03/20/pope-francis-gives-blessing-tattoos/)
and says:

> There is nothing wrong with tattoos, Pope Francis told a group of
> young people Monday, urging them to be open to cultural expressions of
> “belonging.”

Pope's statement totally contradicts the Bible's verse.

What is the official Catholic teaching on getting tattoos of any kind?

Comment: Looks like this one has already been asked – do those answers address your question?

Comment: @Nathaniel, Thanks. Why isn't the answer accepted in the duplicate?

Comment: Not sure; that's up to the person asking the question.